# Why electron self-energy and other processes like vacuum polarization is not possible classically?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, self-energy

Why electron self-energy and other processes like vacuum polarization is not possible classically?

Comment: Classical off shell processes? Classical virtual particles? What would you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. I know that classical theory is linear and it considers electron a s spherical charge but still not satisfied with the interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Classical field theory (or first quantized theory, if you will) is tantamount to tree approximation (or saddle point approximation in path integral formulation) in quantum field theory, while 'electron self-energy and other processes like vacuum polarization' involve loop corrections, which are purely of quantum (second quantization) origin.